# Running ubuntu20.04 guest operating system crashes with error "The CPU has been disabled by the guest operating system."

Tags: vmware, python3

I am running a virtual machine ubuntu 20.04 (5.11.0-051100-generic kernel) machine in vmware esxi server (6.5).

While working with a python code which takes a connection to another machine and execute a command  using pexpect module the guest operating system crashes with the below error.

```
The CPU has been disabled by the guest operating system. Power off or reset the virtual machine.
```

**Detailed Log**

```
9:13:59.142Z| vcpu-1| I125: AHCI-VMM: sata0:28: Exiting COMRESET state.
9:13:59.449Z| vcpu-0| I125: AHCI-USER: Already in check condition 02 3a 01
9:13:59.498Z| vmx| I125: CDROM sata0:0: CMD 0x5a (MODE SENSE(10)) FAILED (key 0x5 asc 0x20 ascq 0)
9:14:01.415Z| svga| I125: SVGA hiding SVGA
9:14:01.417Z| vcpu-1| I125: Guest: vmwgfx: In Tree-Unknown
9:14:01.417Z| vcpu-1| I125: Guest: vmwgfx: Module Version: 2.18.0
9:14:01.417Z| svga| I125: SVGA enabling SVGA
9:14:01.432Z| svga| I125: SVGA-ScreenMgr: Screen type changed to ScreenTarget
9:14:01.959Z| vcpu-0| I125: Tools: Running status rpc handler: 0 => 1.
9:14:01.959Z| vcpu-0| I125: Tools: Changing running status: 0 => 1.
9:14:01.959Z| vcpu-0| I125: Tools: Removing Tools inactivity timer.
9:14:02.413Z| vcpu-2| I125: VMXNET3 user: Ethernet0 Driver Info: version = 17104896 gosBits = 2 gosType = 1, gosVer = 0, gosMisc = 0
9:14:22.960Z| vcpu-0| I125: Tools: Tools heartbeat timeout.
9:14:22.960Z| vcpu-0| I125: Tools: Running status rpc handler: 1 => 0.
9:14:22.960Z| vcpu-0| I125: Tools: Changing running status: 1 => 0.
9:14:47.608Z| vcpu-3| I125: APIC THERMLVT write: 0x10000
9:14:47.608Z| vcpu-2| I125: APIC THERMLVT write: 0x10000
9:14:47.608Z| vcpu-1| I125: APIC THERMLVT write: 0x10000
**9:14:47.608Z| vcpu-0| I125: APIC THERMLVT write: 0x10000
9:14:47.608Z| vcpu-0| I125: Vix: [2898800 vmxCommands.c:7212]: VMAutomation_HandleCLIHLTEvent. Do nothing.
9:14:47.608Z| vcpu-0| I125: MsgHint: msg.monitorevent.halt
9:14:47.608Z| vcpu-0| I125+ The CPU has been disabled by the guest operating system. Power off or reset the virtual machine.**
9:14:47.608Z| vcpu-0| I125+
```

Did some searching on this error and applied some workarounds related to this error.

- Upgrade the kernel to 5.11.0-051100-generic kernel.
- setting

  ```
  modprobe.blacklist=intel_powerclamp
  ```

  inside `/etc/default/grub` file.
- setting

  ```
  cpuid.1.eax = "0000:0000:0000:0001:0000:0110:1010:0101"
  ```

  in `Ubuntu 20.04.vmx` file
- Enabled the

  ```
  vhv.enable = "true"
  ```

  in `Ubuntu 20.04.vmx` file.

But none of this solved the issue. Can anyone help on this.

Comment: Is virtualization enabled in the BIOS?

Comment: Yes I have enabled it.vhv.enable = "true" is showing in vmx file

Answer (score 0):

I was the same issue, the solution was to change the network adapter, to use E1000E instead of VMXNET. You can try it, goog luck.